# PHP on IIS/Win2k8

Tags: php, iis

My question is what does PHP do to performance and stability when i install it on my Windows 2008 server which has a dozen of .NET web applications running.

Would it affect the perfomance of my server/web applications? 
Any advise would be welcome.

Thanks,
Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

personally i am running PHP on 2008 server box within Amazon's Cloud system, so far i have not really seen any sort of system degredation, preformance slowdown or instabilities.

admittidaly i do not run a large or busy system compared to some peoples servers but from my person experience i have not seen a problem to date.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Windows 2008 and IIS 7.0 have new features and optimizations that allow PHP to run more efficiently and robustly.   The most significant improvement Microsoft made was to update the CGI support in IIS 7.0 to conform to the Fast CGI standard.  Fast CGI saves a process create/destroy operation per request by pooling and reusing multiple worker processes.  This translates into significant performance improvements for PHP applications on Windows.
>   By default, the Fast CGI support in IIS 7.0 is configured to be conservative when allocating resources in order to best support the scenario where hundreds of web sites are running on a single physical server.

From [Tuning Windows Server 2008 for PHP](http://blogs.technet.com/b/winserverperformance/archive/2008/07/25/tuning-windows-server-2008-for-php.aspx).

Personally, we've just setup PHP (using the Web Platform Installer - I'd recommend you do the same) on one of our corporate servers, and outside of an increase in memory usage due to a couple WordPress sites, we've experienced no other noticeable issues.

I've personally installed PHP on two of my servers, and again have experienced no issues, although I don't really use PHP on those machines.

So, realistically, the only impact should be from the PHP applications running on the machine.

Can I ask why you want to install PHP on this machine? Is it to move existing apps over to the server, for experimentation, or ... ?